# urllib2 IncompleteRead error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
urllib2.urlopen('http://muhlenberg.edu/alumni/').geturl()
```

This should return http://www.muhlenbergconnect.com/s/1570/index.aspx?gid=2&pgid=61/ which is the link that it gets redirected to. However, I get an IncompleteRead error when running that code.

Is there a way I can prevent this error from happening and still return the correct link?

Comment: Have you tried [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org)? It is known to take care of these issues automatically.

Comment: I believe I found my solution, getting a request a using r.url seems to work! Thank you. It does, however, seem to be a bit slow. Is there a faster solution?